# Look up Enum by label instead of by value

Tags: enums, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a quick way to look up an Enum with only using the label of the enum instead of the value.  Let's say the Enum type is SalesStatus, I want to be able to basically call into some kind of a function like enumLabel2Value(enumStr(SalesStatus), "Open order") and it will return 1.

I'm trying to avoid looping thru all possible values and checking each one separately, it seems like this should be something that's readily available since whenever a user filters on a enum column on a grid, they enter in the label, not the value, but I haven't seen anything like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [str2Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa655065.aspx) function for that. From the documentation:

> Retrieves the enum element whose localized **Label** property value
>   matches the input string.

In addition to the caveats from Alex Kwitny's answer, I recommend taking a look at the comments of the documentation, specifically the comment

> Please note that str2Enum performs partial matching and matches the
>   beginning of the string. If there are multiple matches, it will take
>   the first one.

In addition take a look at method `string2Enum` of class `DMFEntityBase`, which supports different options how the enum element can be specified. I think with the [DictEnum.name2Value()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dictenum.name2value.aspx) method enum elements specified by their label are handled.

**Update**

OP mentioned in the comments to Alex Kwitny's answer that it is a specific enum `ExchangeRateDisplayFactor` he has issues with. `str2Enum` also works with that enum, as the following job demonstrates:

```cs
static void str2EnumTest(Args _args)
{
    ExchangeRateDisplayFactor factor;

    factor = str2Enum(factor, '1');
    info(strFmt('%1', factor)); // outputs '1'
    factor = str2Enum(factor, '10');
    info(strFmt('%1', factor)); // outputs '10'
    factor = str2Enum(factor, '100');
    info(strFmt('%1', factor)); // outputs '100'
    factor = str2Enum(factor, '1000');
    info(strFmt('%1', factor)); // outputs '1000'
    factor = str2Enum(factor, '10000');
    info(strFmt('%1', factor)); // outputs '10000'
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I didn't have AX in front of me and was just thinking how an efficient function couldn't exist that was any better than a 3 or 4 line loop.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't exist because labels can be all sorts of things in different languages. `symbol2Value()` exists though and may be what you're looking for, but your question is specifically on labels. An example of where this could be very bad...

Let's say you have an enum called `GoodBadPresent`, to indicate what type of Christmas present you will receive, with two values:

1. `GoodBadPresent::Poison` English label: "Poison"; German label: "**Gift**"
2. `GoodBadPresent::Gift` English label: "**Gift**"; German label: "Geschenk"

If this example isn't clear, the word for `Poison` in German is `Gift`. So if you tried to resolve `Gift` to an enum value, you'd also have to provide the language. The performance problems here are probably greater than the performance problems of looping through an enum.

You can look at `DictEnum` to see if there are any methods that can help you more succinctly achieve what you want though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg837824.aspx

I'm more curious to the details of your scenario where you need to get back to an enum from a label.

Comment: Specifically, I'm developing a solution to add a custom Currency Exchange Rate Provider to the system and one of the fields being sent to us in a CSV file is the Quotation unit, which correlates to enum ExchangeRateDisplayFactor.  The CSV file will give values of 1, 10, 100, 1000, or 10000, which exactly match the labels set forth for each of the enums.  It seems like FH's answer would've worked if the labels in this case weren't all numbers.

Comment: I see. You should just create your own EDT that matches the enum values of `ExchangeRateDisplayFactor` such as `MyExchangeRateDisplayFactor` and then use basic assignment `ExchangeRateDisplayFactor = MyExchangeRateDisplayFactor` to convert or a million other options. That or you can create a config table where you setup `1` = `ExchangeRateDisplayFactor::One`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid the if(value == "1") return Enum::FactorOne; if (value == "10") return Enum::FactorTen; etc. or looping thru DictEnum.  Creating a new enum doesn't solve the issue, 10000 is not a valid option for a value.  There's gotta be a simpler way tho, the same mechanism that AX uses when users filter by grid...

Comment: Probably the best option would be an import mapping config table. Where you key in the arbitrary values and then select an enum value to map it to. Then during import you just query/join the table and resolve the enum.

Comment: @codemann8 `str2Enum` also works with enum `ExchangeRateDisplayFactor`, see my updated answer.